# problem in upgrading scikit-image version

Tags: python, scikit-learn, version, upgrade

On my system spyder version  '0.13.1' is installed and I want to use
from skimage.filters import unsharp_mask
the error comes:
ImportError: cannot import name 'unsharp_mask
then I treid to upgrade the version using:
1st passed;
!pip install scikit-image
then I passed:
!pip install --upgrade scikit-image
then still version is same which is  '0.13.1'.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resloved with the help of Anaconda official video tutorial :
https://anaconda.cloud/tutorials/getting-started-with-anaconda-individual-edition?source=install